# jqGrid table search

Tags: search, jqgrid

How can I get a jQgrid without editing and having select search elements as like:

```
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ToolbarSearchValidation.htm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved:

```
stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ":All;true:Yes;false:No"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the demo that you've linked to is using jqGrid's filterToolbar feature:

see: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching

Comment: But how to have the `tax` column at that page? It has a select element at search.

Comment: You have some more research to do. The settings you want are **editoptions** and **edittype: select**. See http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions

Comment: @ Walter Stabosz thanks for your help I tried but didn't work. Can you show me a code example?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I've never written code to user the toolbar_searching feature, so I can't give you a code sample. You will have to do the research and code it yourself. 

Try creating a basic grid with editable rows that use a select list. If you have trouble with that, then maybe jqGrid is too advanced for you.

Comment: @ Walter Stabosz thanks for your help,  not advanced for me just wiki is not explaining something. I solved the problem.